# How to group radioboxes to a controlgroup in jQuery Mobile correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need these radio's to be connected - only one option has to be chosen at once. Please check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdsGu/39/) or the following code and open my eyes...

```
<div id="my-controlgroup" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" class="confine-radiobuttons">
    <legend>options</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="documents-all" name="documents-all" value="all" checked="checked">
    <label for="documents-all">all</label>

    <input type="radio" id="documents-marked" name="documents-marked" value="transactionrelevant">
    <label for="documents-marked">marked only</label>
```

Comment: The Fiddle is broken :(
However, the code you pasted is missing a closing of the <div> element.

Comment: sorry - I corrected the link.

Comment: `name` should be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for radio buttons to be "connected" they must have the same name. Yours have the names `documents-all` and `documents-marked`. You must change one to match the other.

Comment: great. I tried that before but it was not working. I must have had a spelling error or something. thnx!